# I need help in creating a ER model for my database

Tags: database, entity-relationship

The description of what the database for is:

##### Stock Management System

This system aims to regulate and track inventory-based materials, allowing the organization to keep track of material levels and thus avoid shortages and improve purchases and storage

##### Import Procedures

The organization evaluates the inventory and identifies its requirements for various materials. It then makes a so-called list of orders containing all the names and quantities of the necessary materials in the warehouse. After they are certified by the director of the enterprise, the supplier will bring the materials, any purchase of them. An invoice will be made containing the same information and names of the materials that were ordered in advance.

##### Procedures for receipt and registration of materials

After the shipment arrives it is checked and made sure it matches the invoice and order list.
By verifying the safety of the material as well as the quantities present
The storage teams store the material and record each material in their own card called the storage card which contains various information about the stored material (date, quantity of inputs, quantity of outputs, quantity in stock, expiration date if any and notes)
Each exit or entry of the substance is registered in this card.

##### Consumption procedures

When consuming a product, the stockholder shall make a document of the substance or substances to be consumed from the inventory called the order document with all the supplies to be consumed, the quantity to be consumed, the consumer, the date and... After it is signed by the consumer and the warehouse administrator, the material or materials are taken out and delivered to the consumer and the warehouse workers update the storage card of each item in terms of date, quantity of outputs, inputs, quantity remaining in stock.

Here my try:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbQ2y.jpg)

For the attributes and the foreign keys I'll add them later after confirming that my design is correct.

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _I have determined the entities and relationships and cardinality, but I think I'm wrong._ I suggest that you [edit] your question and post the entities relationships and cardinality. Then someone may be able to tell you if you are wrong (or not).